# Can I enter a Schengen area country for the first time by land? Or does it have to be via flight?

Tags: schengen-visas

I'll be travelling to Russia. And I was planning to apply for a Schengen Visa so that I can take the train from St. Petersburg to Helsinki. Is entry by land in this manner allowed?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, plenty of people enter the Schengen area by land, even without having ever flown there.